# How to assure that some content is always stacked behind the main content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, advertisement-server

We have some ads on our site delivered by an ad server. You know ads are delivered by lots of JavaScript, redirect, flash and all this ugly stuff.

Most of the time everything works.

But on some rare conditions like older browsers or whatever, the ad does not have the correct position and is lying above the content (not on purpose like a popup, layer or interstitial what we don't have at all)

I don't want to have ads lying above my content so if they do something wrong they should not show up at all.

All this ad markup is in a `<div id="ad">...</div>`. Is there a reliable way to have all this content stacked **behind** the other content regardless of what is pushed inside this div?

Answers like "Tell the adserver/campaing manager/etc to do the right thing" does not help me. I need a technical solution on my site.

Comment: Might be worth reading up on the `z-index` property : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: It might be useful to show an example ad that you get from your adserver.

Comment: Ads would normally have separate area (divs / sections) allocated to them in your HTML markup. It seems very odd that any ad service would just randomly put them inside existing content divs where they could obscure the content. I think more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [z-index](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/):

Just set all your divs to something like 10 and all adds to 0.

i.e

```
div { /*so all your website content appears on top*/
    z-index: 10;
}

.myadd {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: But the ad itself will give a z-index of 1000. Also you have to take care of stacking groups. and so on. It is not so easy.

Comment: Without giving more info, this is the best you are going to get. Why do the ids give an index of 1000, where is that info in your op.

Comment: I am admitting that my question was rather vague. But with ads you can't predict what they put into the div. So I thought of a general solution something with jquery analyzing the two divs and see the resulting stack position if they are overlapping. I will investigate further.